# PHP регулярка только русские буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как регуляркой разрешить ввод только русских букв?
Пробовала так, не получается `/[а-я]/`

Comment: Пробуйте `/[А-Яа-я]+/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = 'Текст';

if (preg_match('/^[а-я]+$/iu', $text)) {
    echo 'Правильно';
} else {
    echo 'Неправильно';
}
```

Comment: Работает) Спасибо) а как запретить еще и ввод пробелов?

Comment: @Кристина пробелы в моем примере - запрещены. Только русские буквы

Comment: @Manitikyl зачем у вас модификатор `s`?

Comment: @Эдуард убраль.